# How to add query result single column to different table?

Tags: sql-server

As you know with AS statement we can create a single column including query expressions. How can I add this single column to my table?

For example:

```
select 
    CAST(idwYear AS varchar(20)) + '-' + 
       CAST((right('00' + ltrim(str(idwMonth)), 2)) AS varchar(20)) + '-' +
       CAST(right('00' + ltrim(str(idwDay)), 2) AS varchar(20)) AS finaldate
```

Now, how can I add final date to for example `my_table`?

Answer (score 0):

That's the solution.

```
insert into finaldate  
    select 
        CAST(idwYear AS varchar(20)) + '-' +
           CAST((right('00' + ltrim(str(idwMonth)), 2)) as varchar(20)) + '-' +
           CAST(right('00' + ltrim(str(idwDay)), 2) AS varchar(20)) 
    from 
        database.dbo.rawdata
```

why I cant do is I added values but no need to values statement

Answer (score 0):

You can add finaldate as a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx) to the table using the DDL below:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.my_table
    ADD finaldate AS
          CAST(idwYear AS varchar(20)) + '-'
        + CAST((right('00' + LTRIM(STR(idwMonth)), 2)) AS varchar(20)) + '-'
        + CAST(right('00' + LTRIM(STR(idwDay)), 2) AS varchar(20));
```